# How do I move an object from one array to another?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to move an object from one array(triviaDataArray) to another(answeredQuestions).  I've replaced the actual questions with numbers to shorten code.  When I run this code it seems to remove a position in the triviaDataArray, and adds one to the answeredQuestion array. But it doesn't seem to remove the correct one.  When a new question is loaded it sometimes repeats itself, which is not what I want.  I want it to ask a question, and then when it is answered move it to the answeredQuestion array.
I can only use JavaScript.  Can someone please help me.  I've been struggling with this for quite some time.

This portion is from a data reader file I have to load a random question and it's answers from an array and the second is to open the array.

```
TriviaDataRecords.prototype.loadRandomRecord = function () {
this.position = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.records.length);
};

function openTriviaRecords(triviaData) {
return new TriviaDataRecords(triviaData);
}
```

global arrays and variables

```
var triviaDataArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
var answeredQuestions = []
var triviaRecords = openTriviaRecords(triviaDataArray);
```

function that loads a question and files the fields of the html.

```
function loadQuestion(){
var randomRecord = triviaRecords.loadRandomRecord();    
var buttonA = document.getElementById("answer1");
var buttonB = document.getElementById("answer2");
var buttonC = document.getElementById("answer3");
var buttonD = document.getElementById("answer4");
var buttonE = document.getElementById("answer5");
document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = triviaRecords.getQuestion();
document.getElementById('answer1').innerHTML = triviaRecords.getAnswerA();
document.getElementById('answer2').innerHTML = triviaRecords.getAnswerB();
document.getElementById('answer3').innerHTML = triviaRecords.getAnswerC();
document.getElementById('answer4').innerHTML = triviaRecords.getAnswerD();
document.getElementById('answer5').innerHTML = triviaRecords.getAnswerE();
```

portion where I'm trying to move the question from one array to another.

```
var index = triviaDataArray.indexOf(randomRecord);
if (index == -1) {
triviaDataArray.splice(randomRecord, 1);
    answeredQuestions.push(randomRecord);
}
```

Comment: `.splice(randomRecord //this should be an` **index** `, 1);` Why is this done `if index == -1` (meaning it's **not** in the array)?

Comment: I have the if statement at -1 because that's the index value of the randomRecord when I console.log it  So are you saying that the randomRecord variable is not in the array that I am trying to pull from?

Comment: Think you better read up on [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: Note that indexOf will only match on objects if your two elements share the same references.  If they only happen to share the same data, it won't be enough.  I don't know if that's the issue, but it sounds possible.